# Can I use step functions to check whether a lambda is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a series of lambdas, one of which I want to execute once another lambda has executed and stopped executing. Is it possible, using step functions, to have a choice state which will check if a lambda is executing?

Comment: Not sure why you want to check if a Lambda function is running, but yes, you can trigger Lambda B when Lambda A has completed. That's pretty fundamental to Step Functions.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, Step Functions trigger tasks (such as a Lambda function execution) based on other tasks completion (success or error).

If the first lambda is in your Step Function then, once it has completed, Step Functions will run the next Step, etc... until it reaches completion. Said next Step could be a choice state checking wether the first lambda has successfully completed or errorred (which would be pointless since you can directly handle an error in a better way (see [Amazon States Language Errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-errors.html)).

But if what you want is to monitor the execution of a Lambda running *'outside of your Step Function'*. This would take some more work, is not implemented *'out of the box'*, and I would whole-heartedly ask you to think about what you're trying to achieve here before going down that road.